# using kafka-console-producer.sh through a proxy

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a linux dev box where I have downloaded kafka. The dev box is on-prem and my kafka cluster is off-prem, in the cloud.
Is it possible to run kafka-console-producer.sh from my dev box through a proxy to my kafka cluster? TIA

Answer (score 0):

There are third party Kafka proxy solutions on Github, or commercially offered by Conduktor, as one example. These are TCP proxies.

Confluent, Strimzi, and others have HTTP proxies.

Out of the box, Kafka does not easily allow proxying without modifying the server properties

https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Otherwise, you do not need a proxy. You can produce to any Kafka cluster, with any Kafka CLI, given the appropriate credentials, where required